# Function to check if a page belongs to lifterlms course plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

Does LifterLMS plugin in wordpress provide any function with which we can check that current page has lifterLMS sections or is a page of LifterLMS, as we have in bbpress `is_bbpress()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to my own question after spending some extra time in the LifterLMS docs

https://lifterlms.com/docs/lifterlms-conditional-tags/

the above link provides all required conditional tags (if you want custom you can create one yourself).